# how do I solve $y -\sin y= 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to use trigonometric equations to solve $y - \sin y = 1$, such as solving for $y$ but it is not working out, I have found $\cos y = \sqrt{-y^2 + y}$ but it does not lead to anywhere useful. I have used wolfram for the answer, but I am not sure how they got it

Comment: There is no closed-form expression for a solution, but one can show using elementary calculus that there is exactly one solution.

Comment: the derivative is 1 - cos(y) = 0, but this gives $y = 0$

Comment: Do you need to show there exists a solution, there exists exactly one solution or numerically approximate a solution?

Comment: I need to approximate one

Comment: @pinkcard If you're looking for an approximate solution, you should mention that in your question. Anyway, Newton's Method is a standard approach to finding numerical approximation of roots.

Comment: I thought there is an exact solution, can I ask why there is not?

Comment: @Travis also how would you go about proving there is exactly one solution? and I am not sure how you knew there wasnt a closed form expression

Comment: There is *some* solution, it just can't be written using familiar, elementary functions. I know this from experience with the involved functions. In general, one cannot find closed-form solutions to equations where the variable appears both inside and outside trigonometric functions, except for certain special values of some parameter. For example, there are closed form solutions to the similar equation $y - \sin y = 0$ (namely $0$) and $y - \sin y = \pi$ (namely, $\pi$) but not the one written.

Comment: One can show that there is a single solution using the fact that $y - \sin y$ has derivative $1 - \cos y$, which is nonnegative for all $y$ (so the function is increasing), together with the fact that it is equal to $y$ only at isolated points.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said in the comments, there is no closed form solution.
[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20-%20siny%20%3D%201) gives the following solution (which you can find using the various numerical methods out there, a few of which are taught in highschool).

We can numerically find that $y \approx 1.93456$.